# 1 year monthly summary with share percentage

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an advance report for my app. And now i'm facing a trouble with some query.

Here's the details:

table_product

```
 id  | name
-----+---------
 1   | Book
 2   | Pen
 3   | Ruler
 4   | Calendar
 5   | Scissors
```

table_event

```
 id  | name
-----+---------
 1   | Launching
 2   | Sale
 3   | Roadshow
 4   | Presentation
 5   | Normal
```

table_transaction

```
---+------------+-------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
id | date       | event | product_1 | share_1 | product_2 | share_2 | product_3 | share_3 |  amount  |
---+------------+-------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
 1 | 2013-01-12 |   1   |    3      |   50    |     2     |    50   |           |         |  5000    |
 2 | 2013-02-13 |   3   |    2      |   50    |     1     |    25   |     4     |   25    |  10000   |
 3 | 2013-01-13 |   5   |    5      |   50    |     4     |    50   |           |         |  7000    |
 4 | 2013-04-13 |   2   |    1      |   100   |           |         |           |         |  5000    |
---+------------+-------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

What I want to display is like this

```
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
Product Name  |  Jan  |  Feb  |  Mar  |  Apr  |  May  |  Jun  |  Jul  |  Aug  |  Sep  |  Oct  |  Nov  |  Dec  |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
 Book         |       | 2500  |       | 5000  |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
 Pen          | 2500  | 5000  |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
 Ruler        | 2500  |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
 Calendar     | 3500  | 2500  |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
 Scissors     | 3500  |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

What I have tried:
I successfully generate the output for event name grouping with following query

```
SELECT t1.name as sort_name, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 1, t2.amount, 0)) as total_jan, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 2, t2.amount, 0)) as total_feb, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 3, t2.amount, 0)) as total_mar, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 4, t2.amount, 0)) as total_apr, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 5, t2.amount, 0)) as total_may, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 6, t2.amount, 0)) as total_jun, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 7, t2.amount, 0)) as total_jul, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 8, t2.amount, 0)) as total_aug, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 9, t2.amount, 0)) as total_sep, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 10, t2.amount, 0)) as total_oct, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 11, t2.amount, 0)) as total_nov, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 12, t2.amount, 0)) as total_dec, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013, t2.amount, 0)) as event_total 
FROM events t1 
LEFT JOIN transactions t2 ON t2.event_id = t1.id 
GROUP BY sort_name
```

But I don't have any idea to do group it by product. I've tried playing with union but still return a SQL syntax error.

Comment: Just select from `table_product` instead of `events` (What are you not telling us?)

Comment: I've tried that. But since each transaction can have more than 1 products, and each product have each share for the amount, it will only select one product for each transaction.

Comment: Ahh....I get it. There's a product_1, share_1, product_2, share_2, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your same query, and create a normalized version of `table_product` with a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.name as sort_name, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 1, t2.amount, 0)) as total_jan, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 2, t2.amount, 0)) as total_feb, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 3, t2.amount, 0)) as total_mar, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 4, t2.amount, 0)) as total_apr, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 5, t2.amount, 0)) as total_may, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 6, t2.amount, 0)) as total_jun, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 7, t2.amount, 0)) as total_jul, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 8, t2.amount, 0)) as total_aug, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 9, t2.amount, 0)) as total_sep, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 10, t2.amount, 0)) as total_oct, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 11, t2.amount, 0)) as total_nov, 
    sum(IF(YEAR(t2.date) = 2013 AND MONTH(t2.date) = 12, t2.amount, 0)) as total_dec
FROM table_product t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT product_1 AS product_id, 
        amount * share_1 / (share_1 + COALESCE(share_2,0) + COALESCE(share_3,0))
            AS amount
    FROM table_transaction
    WHERE product_1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product_2 AS product_id, 
        amount * share_2 / (share_2 + COALESCE(share_1,0) + COALESCE(share_3,0))
            AS amount
    FROM table_transaction
    WHERE product_2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product_3 AS product_id, 
        amount * share_3 / (share_3 + COALESCE(share_2,0) + COALESCE(share_1,0))
            AS amount
    FROM table_transaction
    WHERE product_3 IS NOT NULL
) t2 ON t2.product_id = t1.id 
GROUP BY sort_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to join with product table instead of events

Comment: I've tried that. But since each transaction can have more than 1 products, and each product have each share for the amount, it will only select one product for each transaction.